# Generate.php fails when trying to set up FTF

Tags: error, testing, magento-1.14

I am trying to set up FTF on my OSX machine.  Whenever I try to `php generate.php` I get the error messages below.  Any ideas how to fix this?

```
frontend-mbp:utils jmargolis$ php generate.php
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: class in /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/lib/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Page.php on line 135
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:0
PHP   2. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Page->launch() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:28
PHP   3. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Page->generateClass() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/lib/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Page.php:64

Notice: Undefined index: class in /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/lib/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Page.php on line 135

Call Stack:
    0.0003     227960   1. {main}() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:0
    0.2440    2881120   2. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Page->launch() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:28
    0.2862    2881776   3. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Page->generateClass() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/lib/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Page.php:64

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: value in /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php on line 239
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:0
PHP   2. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Fixture->launch() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:29
PHP   3. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Fixture->generateClass() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php:45
PHP   4. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Fixture->getDefaultValue() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php:148

Notice: Undefined index: value in /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php on line 239

Call Stack:
    0.0003     227960   1. {main}() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:0
    0.4327    4764200   2. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Fixture->launch() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/utils/generate.php:29
    0.4489    4765032   3. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Fixture->generateClass() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php:45
    0.4490    4774744   4. Magento\Mtf\Util\Generate\Fixture->getDefaultValue() /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php:148

|| Item               || Count || Time ||
|| Page Classes       || 112   || 0    ||
|| Fixture Classes    || 44    || 0    ||
|| Repository Classes || 38    || 0    ||

frontend-mbp:utils jmargolis$
```

**Edit:** This is not a clean install, but I don't think anyone has ever touched the testing area.

Comment: Could you, please specify what Magento version do you use?
According to your trace there is some error in `PHP Notice: Undefined index: value in /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php on line 239` but in current MTF there no such line https://github.com/magento/mtf/blob/develop/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Fixture.php Also, have you made some changes in the functional tests or it's a clean Magento code?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on the latest Magento 1 code base and could reproduce the same issues. This warnings have already been fixed in the current M1 develop branch which will be available with the next M1 release.

Regarding this issues they won't affect test execution. The reason is incorrect xml files for page and fixture:

- `dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Mage/Customer/Test/Page/CustomerAccountLogout.xml`doesn't contain block class. To avoid this you can add fake class name or to fix page generator dev/tests/functional/lib/Magento/Mtf/Util/Generate/Page.php, just wrap the code below line 133 to

  `if (isset($block['class'])) {
      $content .= "\n    /**\n";
      $content .= "     * @return \\{$block['class']}\n";
      $content .= "     */\n";
      $content .= '    public function get' . ucfirst($blockName) . '()' . "\n";
      $content .= "    {\n";
      $content .= "        return \$this->getBlockInstance('{$blockName}');\n";
      $content .= "    }\n";
  }`
- dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Mage/Catalog/Test/Fixture/CatalogProductAttribute.xml has incorrect default value type for `entity_type_id`, it should be

  `<field name="entity_type_id" is_required="0">
      <default_value xsi:type="null" />
  </field>`

Comment: With your changes, I am now getting this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException' with message ' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php on line 165

PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: this.browser.getBrowserForTab is not a function (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: Perhaps related to [this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130497/how-to-tell-ftf-to-use-my-custom-admin-url)?

Comment: What test did you run? What version of Firefox and Selenium do you use? Take into consideration that selenium server doesn't work with the latest FF version.

Comment: Try to run on the chrome http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_environment.html#mtf_quickstart_env_selenium-non-def