# How to tell FTF to use my custom admin url?

Tags: testing

Even though [generate.php is still failing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130458/generate-php-fails-when-trying-to-set-up-ftf), I've got FTF running, but I keep running into this error:
    **Configuration read from /Applications/AMPPS/www/am.dev/dev/tests/functional/phpunit.xml** where I have the backend url set to my custom url:

```
<env name="app_backend_url" value="http://www.am.dev/my-custom-admin/" />
```

Yet, it keeps trying to hit http://www.am.dev/admin.  Where is the right place to set it to "my-custom-url"?

Comment: Actually it's the right place to set the backend url. Could you, please, tell what test do you run and what Magento version do you use? Also, could you add the full stack trace log.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the file `/magento/dev/tests/functional/etc/config.xml.dist` - provide your values in

```
<application />
```

Here is the documentation for the ftf configuration files:
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/configuration.html